# I want to create quiz

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

i want to create quiz using javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function generateQuiz(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton){
    function showQuestions(questions, quizContainer){
    }
    function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer){
        }
    showQuestions(questions, quizContainer);
    submitButton.onclick = function(){
        showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
    }
}
var myQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What is 10/2?",
        answers: {
            a: '3',b: '5',c: '115'
        },
        correctAnswer: 'b'
    },
    {
        question: "What is 30/3?",
        answers: {
            a: '3',b: '5',c: '10'
        },
        correctAnswer: 'c'
    }
];
function showQuestions(questions, quizContainer){
    var output = [];
    var answers;
    for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++){      
        answers = [];
        for(letter in questions[i].answers){
            answers.push(
                '<label>'
                    + '<input type="radio" name="question'+i+'" value="'+letter+'">'
                    + letter + ': '
                    + questions[i].answers[letter]
                + '</label>'
            );
        }
        output.push(
            '<div class="question">' + questions[i].question + '</div>'
            + '<div class="answers">' + answers.join('') + '</div>'
        );
    }
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
}
showQuestions(questions, quizContainer);
function showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer){
    var answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');
    var userAnswer = '';
    var numCorrect = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<questions.length; i++){
        userAnswer = (answerContainers[i].querySelector('input[name=question'+i+']:checked')||{}).value;
        if(userAnswer===questions[i].correctAnswer){
            numCorrect++;
            answerContainers[i].style.color = 'lightgreen';
        }
        else{
            answerContainers[i].style.color = 'red';
        }
    }
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = numCorrect + ' out of ' + questions.length;
}
submitButton.onclick = function(){
    showResults(questions, quizContainer, resultsContainer);
}
var quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
var resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
generateQuiz(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer, submitButton);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="quiz"></div>
<button id="submit">Get Results</button>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my quiz.html code but I can't get questions in the browser. how can shows questions in the browser and get result?

How to create quiz like fill in blanks, reorder question, etc...

also I want to put this code in Wordpress custom plugin. how I create a custom plugin in Wordpress for the quiz?

Comment: Maybe show the source url where you got this code since it isn't your own would be a start. The quiz code has concepts above your level of understanding perhaps?

Comment: https://simplestepscode.com/javascript-quiz-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

> How to create quiz like fill in blanks, reorder question, etc...

You should store the correct answers on const variables, you should use an array of strings for the "blanks" ones and refer to them by index/question number:

```
const answers = [ "Cygnus", "Rainbows", "42" ];
const questions = [ "What spacecraft has NASA launched several times to supply the ISS?", "What is the name of those optical atmospheric phenomena that produce an almost continuous spectrum of light in the sky when sunlight passes through water drops?", "What is the meaning of life itself?" ];
```

From here it's simple, you know that questions and answers are paired by array indexes:

```
// ans - hypothetical variable that contains the text of the user's answer
let answer0 = (ans.includes(answer[0])) ? "Well done!" : "Wrong!";
```

Or you could be more restrictive on the answer with:

```
let answer0 = (ans === answer[0]) ? "Well done!" : "Wrong!";
```

---

About "reorder question" I'll use always arrays, but comparing a const correct array with the user/player answer array.